# Why does Unit Test fail?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am writing a unit test for a converter that converts a group from a local model to a database one and vice versa. Using Objectbox database. When running a unit test, an error occurs: [image]

How can I fix it?
My Test:

```dart
    main() {
      group('Group converter when user add Group', () {
        test('The result should be a database model converted to a local model',
            () {
          final groupConverter = GroupDbConverter();
          final dbModel = GroupEntity(
            id: 1,
            groupName: 'Test group',
            students: ToMany(),
          );
          final expected = Group(
            id: 1,
            groupName: 'Test group',
            students: [],
          );
          final actual = groupConverter.inToOut(dbModel);
          expect(actual, expected);
        });
      });
    }
```

My models:

```dart
    class Group extends Equatable {
      Group({
        this.id,
        this.groupName,
        this.students,
      });
      int? id;
      String? groupName;
      List<Student>? students;
      @override
      List<Object?> get props => [id, groupName, students];
    }

    @Entity()
    class GroupEntity extends Equatable {
      GroupEntity({
        this.id = 0,
        required this.groupName,
        required this.students,
      });
      int id;
      String groupName;
      @Backlink('group')
      ToMany<StudentEntity> students = ToMany<StudentEntity>();
      @override
      List<Object?> get props => [id, groupName, students];
    }
```

Comment: Code for `inToOut` is missing. Apart from that, fields in Equatable objects should be final https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes

Comment: Whta do you mean: Code for inToOut is missing?

Comment: You are using `groupConverter.inToOut(dbModel)` in your unit test, but the code for that method is actually missing.